# Login form using xcode and tablecells

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I am aware there are similar questions to this one but as my approach is different I am going to go ahead and ask. I have a tableview controller which I intend to use as a login form for my app. It should consist of two sections; the first section has two tablecells; the first row being the username textfield and the second the password textfield, the second section would have just one row which would serve as a sign in button. I have been able to achieve the username and password section but since the second row has only one row it a bit confusing implementing it. Here are samples of my code;

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

}
if ([indexPath section] == 0)
{ // Email & Password Section
    if ([indexPath row] == 0)
    { // Email
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Username";

    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Password";
    }
}

if ([indexPath section] == 1)
{
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Sign In to App";
}
return cell;
```

}

The second section produces two rows where it should have just one, please help thanks.

Comment: You should setup all of your textfields inside viewDidLoad to avoid creating the textfields everytime the row is called. ALthough this shouldn't be a problem since all the rows should always be visible, it's good practice. The only thing in your cellForRowAtIndexPath should be [cell.contentView addSubview:loginID];
[cell.contentView addSubview:password];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please use this code -

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section==0) {
         return 2;
    }
    else
    {
         return 1;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The function `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` always returns 2, so there will be two rows for every section. You should put logic in the function to get number of rows you want.

Comment: Hi thanks, I am aware of this, the reason I wrote it that way is because the first section should have two rows and the second section just one row, that is my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Foobar"];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Foobar"];

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        // create and add your userName TextFierld in cell.contentView;
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 1 && indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        // create and add your Password TextFierld in cell.contentView;
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        // create and add your Login UIButton in cell.contentView;
    }
}
```